How to decorrelate a stochastic process using a filter?
I was given a process $X(n)$ WSS whose autocorrelation function is given by:
$$
\gamma_X(\ell) = \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{|\ell|}
$$
I'm asked to find a filter with an amplitude response $|H(\phi)|$ that "completely decorrelate" the  process.
I have no idea how to deal with it, any help would be invaluable.

What do you understand by the term "completely decorrelate" ? And how does the filter $H$ change the spectrum of the input? How is the spectrum of the input related to the autocorrelation? Answering these questions will move you towards the solution.

@PeterK. Deccorlated sequences means that the autocorrelation of the output $y$ is $0$ for any lag of $\ell$ and $\gamma_Y(\ell)=\gamma_X(\ell)h(\ell)\overline{h(\ell)}$ and its DSP is given by $S_Y(\varphi) = S_X(\varphi) \cdot |H(\varphi)|^2$ ; should I make it equal to a constante as an AWGN noise DSP ?

" the autocorrelation of the output y is 0  for any lag of ℓ". Does that include a lag of $l=0$? The autocorrelation at a lag $l=0$ is the power and there is only signal that a has a power of 0. You should also if you are talking about continuous or discrete random variables, i.e. is $n,l \in \mathbb{R}$ or $n,l \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

You know $S_X(\omega)$ is (I hope), and you know what you want $S_Y(\omega)$ to be, and so you should be able to figure out what $|H(\omega)|^2$ ought to be from $S_Y(\omega)) = S_X(\omega)|H(\omega)|^2$. The hard part is going from $|H(\omega)|^2$ to $H(\omega)$ so as to get a realizable filter.

@Hilmar $n,l \in \mathbb{Z}$, I think it should not include the $l=0$

@DilipSarwate $S_X(\omega)$ is a representation of the distribution of the process power across different frequencies. it's the fourier transfoem of the autocorrelation wich measurs the correspondence in differents cycles of the process. So the  $S_Y(\omega)$ equal to a constant is valid ?

So, what in your opinion, is the PSD of a discrete-time white noise process?

@DilipSarwate it is a Flat DSP

So, isn't a flat PSD exactly what you want? Why then are you asking "So the $S_Y(\omega)$ equal to a constant is valid?"

@MouhKramo $\mathbb{Z}$ usually means all the integers, including 0 and negative ones.
